# How do I represent a shell script in a UML class diagram?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I'm modelling a small project I've been working on in UML. However, I'm unsure how and if I should include the script I have written to compile the rest of the code in the class diagram. Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really fit, or does it? Shell scripts are mostly about behaviour, that is code that actually runs, the "business logic". But this is almost exactly what class diagrams DO NOT cover. They do only "structure".

Maybe it would make sense in some kind of *component diagram* ("plug in parameters *here*, the shell script will produce something that goes *there*"). I have a hard time imagining how to do it in a class diagram. Maybe just a comment annotation on a part of the diagram?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an activity diagram? It represents behavior. Each activity can take parameters, just like a script, and you can chain them together in call-activity actions.

Answer (score 0):

It's a question of abstraction. And what levels you want to include in your model/documentation. Generally it's a very good idea to include things like configuration management in your model. That is: how must things be compiled, what kind of data maintenance is needed, etc. If you decide to do that, you just introduce appropriate packages. The usage of CIM/PIM/CSM will just point to to CSM where you can place these deployment relevant things. A class or just an artifact can represent your script and you can relate it to the process behind it. This behavioral part can be modeled via use cases/activities and/or sequence diagrams.